# How to secure application source code

Tags: android, decompiler

I have an application and I need to secure/prevent my application source code.
I need that no one can get my application code by using any of the tool with the help of apk file.

I found that by using below steps, someone can get the application source code from apk file.
i.e. If someone get the apk file so He/She can easily find out the source code of an application by using its apk.

By following this link, you can easily get the source code from apk file : 
[how to extract code of apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file)

I just want to protect my application source code.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you feel you need to obfuscate your application? The usual answer to this question is that you don't.

Answer (score 5):

To tell the full story, there is no way to completely prevent people from copying and reverse-engineering the APK. While there is no way to completely secure your code, the best you can do us make it as hard as possible to understand the decompiled code. This is where Proguard comes in: It obfuscates your code, meaning it modifies the code in a way that makes it impossible to recover Class, Member and Function names from the APK.

[ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) is a free tool that is included in the Android SDK.
There also is a commercial version with additional functionality called DexGuard available [here](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard).

Comment: Note that the code is still relatively understandable even after Proguard. All it will do is discourage casual users from looking.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Explains how to secure your code.