# Get the Main Package Name of an .apk File

Tags: java, android, command-line, android-emulator, adb

I have to launch an application on android emulator using command line.for that I have knew that there is a method by adb command;

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.myApplication
```

but I have to find the application package name before executing this command, so anybody help me to find the package name, or any alternate solution for running apk on emulator

Comment: What kind of packages do you want to get? We just need to get your problem first.

Comment: i want to get the application package name of main activity, like I specified in the command line argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract the apk file and rebuilt the manifest file, then by parsing the xml manifest file you can find the main activity package name.
refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package) for parsing, and refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file) for extracting apk file.

Answer (score 11):

On Linux, simply use this command to get package name:

`aapt dump badging {apk-file.apk} | grep package | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g`

Getting main (launcher) activity is similar:

`aapt dump badging {apk-file.apk} | grep launchable-activity: | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g`

For my personal usage, I've written a shell script called `apkinfo.sh` as following:

`` #!/bin/bash 
package=`aapt dump badging $* | grep package | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g`
activity=`aapt dump badging $* | grep launchable-activity: | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g`
echo
echo package : $package
echo activity: $activity ``

And use it as following:

`./apkinfo.sh {path-to-apk-file.apk}`

Answer (score 4):

```
aapt dump badging <path-to-apk>
```

Comment: this command shows the complete information of the application, I need only package name.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for this in one of my projects, inside a shell script.

```
apk= #apk path
package=`.//aapt dump badging $apk | grep package | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g`
echo $package
adb install $apk
```

if you want to just enter in cmd prompt, then it would be

```
.//aapt dump badging ***apk relative path*** | grep package | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/name=//g | sed s/\'//g
```

that should work.

Comment: shows error grep is not recognized as internal external command

Comment: are you on linux or mac?

Comment: Also if the app is on the google play store, you can view it and the package name is displayed at the end of the URL.

Comment: Ok. Well ypu cant grep on windows. So thats my method out the window, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Andgroguard](https://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)

This is how I did in Python3:

```
from androguard.misc import AnalyzeAPK
a, d, dx = AnalyzeAPK(apk_file)
package_name = a.get_package()
print(package_name)
```