# Better way to extract files from apk

Tags: java, android, apk, apktool

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file) method for extracting the Java and XML files from the apk file but my Java files have a lot of modifications which for sure wasn't there in the original code.

For example, in one class appears for several times `access$902`, `access$902` ,string of digits like `2130903064`. They appear in the place of other methods or variables and the project doesn't build because of them.

Can be there extracted the original files or is a solution for this problem? Thanks

Comment: You aren't "extracting" java files, you are decompiling object code into some algorithm's guess as to what readable corresponding source might look like.

Comment: Ok then.. So there isn't any possibilities to get the original sources?

Comment: No, of course not.  Unless they chose to publish them somewhere, only the developer has those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Because build process generate `.class` files, and reverse engineering nevers get to the original code (AFAIK).

If the `.apk` file was generated using the [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), this will be less readable and more difficult to understand.

The best alternative is use the [AndroChef](http://www.neshkov.com/ac_decompiler.html) java decompiler, that runs in windows. This tool can allow you to change the method / variable / class names to be more readable, including the generated files.

The original code only the developer / company owns. I hope you are not using this for something illegal.