# Android, Is there any way to recover app files from an installed app?

Tags: android

I had a problem with my pc and I had to format the c drive without being able to access it, good things is that i only lost my app files, bad news is that I lost my app files hahah (not really laughing at all, more like a crying laugh). I used to test my app in my phone so i have it installed there, i have half of the progress I've made backed up (too bad i didn't change the app's folder, I am gonna do it from now on) but i would reaply like to recover it, so... Is there any way that can be done? If not well...  learned the lesson the hard way I guess

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic, so I'll add a comment. Google is your friend: if you can get the apk file from the device, you can use tools like dex2jar and apktool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to retrieve the java classes and resources from the apk. First, you can try pulling the apk from your Android device:

[How do I get an apk file from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032960/how-do-i-get-an-apk-file-from-an-android-device)

Second, try retrieving java files from the apk:

[how to extract code of apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is called reverse engineering.
Here's a tool that might help you: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Hope you will recover your code ;)