# How to recover a project that is installed on my smartphone

Tags: android, apk, smartphone

My computer messed up due to a storm and unfortunately I lost everything I had in HD including some projects I was doing in android. But they are installed on my smartphone was wondering if you can recover them with just that.
Please help me thank you

Comment: This is why you should always use a version control system.  There's enough that are free that there's no reason not to.

Comment: truth. Now I will use some version control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't recover the app project, but you can check the code extracting the apk from your phone and decompiling it.

To extract the APK from your phone use this APP:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newpower.apkmanager

Use this website to decompile your APK

http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Answer (score 2):

1. Search for the .apk file on your smart phone file system.
2. You may be able to unzip the apk file, to retrieve the Java .class files.
3. Use a Java decompiler like jad on the .class files.

This may be a duplicate of:

[how to extract code of apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file)